# Can you output an Azure Logic App Variable to file and store on blob storage?

Tags: azure, variables, scope, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have searched google and MSDN and it's not clear if you can write a variable to blob storage? Searching the available steps/actions does not yield anything obvious either.

I have constructed an array variable of file names from an SFTP in per the following documentation, but I can't figure out if this can be stored or saved in any capacity.

Right now it seems these variables are essentially internal to the logic app and can't be made external or is there a way to export them?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-variables-store-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just simply want to save the variable's value in a blob then you can do so with the [Azure Blob Storage - Create Blob action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblobconnector/#create-blob):

[image]